# Why isn't iTunes starting on my mac?

Tags: itunes, crash

I am trying to figure out why iTunes is not starting on my mac.  When I double-click on iTunes.app in the finder, I get the usual animation of the icon indicating that the app is starting, but then nothing happens.

Digging a little deeper, I see the following entries being created in the console:

```
2015-05-10 7:21:11.710 PM pkd[445]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.appextension.state
com.apple.message.action: Uninstalled
com.apple.message.name: com.apple.iTunes.today.TodayExtension-1.0
com.apple.message.reorder_direction: 0
com.apple.message.source: Apple
com.apple.message.type: com.apple.widget-extension
SenderMachUUID: 58242545-21FA-3D58-8722-ED1C2E256DB6

2015-05-10 7:21:11.720 PM pkd[445]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.appextension.state
com.apple.message.action: Installed
com.apple.message.name: com.apple.iTunes.today.TodayExtension-12.1.2.27
com.apple.message.reorder_direction: 0
com.apple.message.source: Apple
com.apple.message.type: com.apple.widget-extension
SenderMachUUID: 58242545-21FA-3D58-8722-ED1C2E256DB6
```

This pair of entries is created each time I double-click. There is no other indication that I can see on why iTunes is not starting.

I have recently re-downloaded and installed version 12.1.2 from apple and continue to have the same problem.

I am running Yosemite version 10.10.3 and I can provide any other information that may be useful. Does anyone have any ideas?

---

**EDIT**:

Logged in as *Guest User* and experiencing the same behavior.

Other seemingly related apps (eg- iBooks, keynote, app store, photos) have no trouble opening either as the regular user or as the guest user.

Comment: The first thing I'd try is make a new user account and see if I can get iTunes to launch. Can you add that detail to your question so we can focus on system issues or user account issues?

Comment: @bmike thanks for the suggestion. Will update the question with more info.

Comment: This is one of those occasions I'd try running the combo updater; sometimes it fixes odd glitches - not always, but worth a try - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. I've gotten a workaround, but it is not a fix.  Hopefully, this will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround. Not a fix, but something that allows me to open itunes.  I've created this bash alias:

```
alias itunes='/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes --x &'
```

Now, whenever I type `itunes` in the terminal, the application opens.

The `--x` option is not valid AFAIK. For some reason, passing a command line option kicks iTunes to  open. When passing no parameters, iTunes does not open.

I cannot explain this behavior and would appreciate an explanation if anyone has one.

I'm going to try @Tetsujin's suggestion to see if it provides a complete fix.

Answer (score -2):

Choose Force Quit from the Apple menu, or press Command-Option-Esc.
This is similar to pressing Control-Alt-Delete on a PC.
Select the unresponsive app in the Force Quit window, then click Force Quit.

[image]

Comment: The OP was trying to get iTunes to _start_, not force quit it. This answer has nothing to do with the question asked.